When I press enter or space in Cs50x codepsace, the written lines in front or behind the text cursor get copied
When I am typing in vs code and I press space or enter it will copy the code around it and paste it for example,
int main(void)
{}

and then i press space or enter when the text cursor is inside the brackets i get
int main(void)
{
 }
}

or if I am typing code and I press space it will copy the previous 6 lines or the 6 lines in-front of the text cursor and paste them in front of the text cursor, I don't know if if these are two different issues or the same issue.
I have tried going and turning off all auto complete options and I have no extensions installed.
More examples of the issueenter image description here and then i  put the text cursor at after the semi-colon after the last printf statement and pressed enter and this is what happensenter image description here
i just want to find a way to stop it happening when I press enter or space because it get very annoying

If you have C/C++ extension installed, go to File->Preferences->Settings->Extensions->C/C++->Formatting and play around with checkboxes under C_Cpp > Vc Format options relating to braces

And if you have a LOT of extensions installed, try removing all but C/C++ and cmake. I've used vscode, more recently than in the past, and I haven't run into any normal typing issues. It shouldn't matter, but what OS are you using? Linux, Windows, etc..

Its on chrome, Cs50x has its own codespace on chrome, and I am using it the way it came, I am on Windows, but I don't know how it would affect it, Vscode on Windows is fine just this codespace.
